# Why does using nginx as a reverse proxy break local links?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, node.js

I've just set up nginx as a reverse proxy, so some sites served from the box are served directly by it and others are forwarded to a Node.js server.

The site being served by Node.js, however, is displayed with no CSS or images, so I assume the links are somehow being broken, but don't know why.

The following is the only file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled:

```
server {

    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4
    listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name  dev.my.site;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

    location / {
            root   /var/www;
            index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /myNodeSite {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

I had thought perhaps it was trying to find them in /var/www due to the first entry, but removing that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Can you please save your resulting HTML files from when the proxy is on and when it's off and run `diff` against them?

Comment: No difference in the HTML file at all according to diff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without more details this is just a guess, but on your frontend you've made your node.js available at `/myNodeSite`.  If your node.js site returns something like this:

```
<img src="/images/myimage.png"/>
```

The client will request `/images/myimage.png`...which *will not* get directed to your node.js site, since it doesn't start with `/myNodeSite`.  There are a few solutions:

- Make your node.js application(s) aware of the prefix you're using on the frontend so that they generate appropriate links.  *Always* generate links via some sort of function that takes this into account, rather than statically encoding links.
- Implement some sort of rewriting feature on the frontend.  I don't know `nginx`, but for Apache there's [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/).

You may also be able to use exclusively relative links (no leading `/`) on your node.js site, but this implies a very flat site layout and is easy to break.

Comment: My brain was almost there but for some reason wasn't quite thinking from the right angle. Cheers.